# Why does Musescore interpret Westergaard's A-flat as G? Seeking Clarification on Pitch Spelling

Tags: key-signatures, accidentals, musescore

I was reviewing some rules from Peter Westergaard's *An Introduction to Tonal Theory*.  I am really only literate in the key of C major, and so I was notating one of Westergaard's example in MuseScore so that I could then transpose the example into the key of C in order to interpret it.  I noticed, however, that MuseScore wasn't allowing me to spell one of the pitches the way it's shown in the text—please see the notes indicated with an arrow in the following images.

[image: Westergaard page 57. The key signature is three flats and there is no time signature (no barlines), there is a series of semibreves several including an A-natural and an A-flat (marked).]

[image: MuseSscore transcription of the above. But there is a time signature and barlines. The marked A has no accidental.]

My confusion lies with the A-flat note indicated by the arrow in the second image. When attempting to lower this A-flat by a half step in MuseScore, it suggests a G instead. My question revolves around whether the accidental added by Westergaard transforms the repeated note into an A-flat or if it's interpreted as a flattened version of the A-flat note diatonic to the key, resulting in a G.

Despite my limited grasp of enharmonic spellings, I'm hoping to understand if this is a fundamental misunderstanding on my part or if there's a difference in presentation between the textbook and MuseScore.

Comment: Not sure if this is important or I'm misreading something: In the first image, the note written as A natural with a label that says "B4" pointing to it is in fact A4 and not B4 - maybe the label isn't there to indicate what note that is, but just in case I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks @ToddWilcox--that is indeed confusing.  The B4 is not related to the pitch but is actually a reference to one of the rules presented in the chapter.

Comment: Aha. Makes sense. I'll leave my comment in case future readers are confused by it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key signature includes Ab.

The first example doesn't use any barlines, so in order to notate Ab after the A natural, one needs to use the flat symbol.

The second example notates one note per measure, so any accidentals, like the natural in the third bar, are cancelled in the following measures. Therefore, the flat symbol is not *needed* in the fifth measure to notate Ab, as the flat comes from the key signature. If you find this notation not clear enough, you can still add a *courtesy* flat symbol in front of the Ab note. In Musescore you can do it using the flat symbols in "Accidentals" palette. It will be redundant, and it will serve as a reminder for the reader. As the accidentals are not additive, it won't lower the note further, to Abb (or G). You may place the flat symbol in parentheses, for extra clarity.

Comment: It’d be nice to also show how to get MuseScore to display the music in free-time (if that’s possible).

Comment: @ElementsInSpace this isn't the question that was asked. By googling I find a suggestion to go to measure properties and change the "actual duration" – but I don't know if it's really the best way to do it. That would be better asked as a separate question.

Comment: @ElementsInSpace asking here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/133410/how-to-notate-free-time-in-musescore

Comment: Good catch.  I read the question four times before I read the answer and didn't even notice the bar lines in the second image.

Comment: @ElementsInSpace In this case, I'd probably just recommend making the barlines invisible, since the notes are already there.

Comment: @trlkly Invisible barlines will still cancel accidentals.

Comment: (Courtesy accidentals are often put in (round) brackets, to show that they don't change anything.  I recommend that, as I find them much less confusing that way.)

Comment: @ElementsInSpace True, but you can always either hide them or add extras when necessary. That said, when I wrote that, I didn't know about the "join measures" function which would also work. Though, again, you'd want to make sure the accidentals are correct, as Musescore can screw them up.