# How to notate free time in MuseScore

Tags: time-signatures, musescore

Inspired by this question: [Why does Musescore interpret Westergaard's A-flat as G? Seeking Clarification on Pitch Spelling](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/133407/why-does-musescore-interpret-westergaards-a-flat-as-g-seeking-clarification-on/133408?noredirect=1#comment250945_133408)

---

Let's say I would like to notate some sequence of notes in MuseScore, without any meter, barlines, possibly without any rhythm. I found a suggestion to adjust the measure's "actual duration" in the measure properties. So e.g. in order to place 10 consecutive whole notes, I could set the measure duration to 40/4. But it seems quite inconvenient, because if I don't fill all 10 notes, MuseScore will add rests, and if I exceed 10 notes, I will need to adjust the "actual duration" again. I wonder if there is an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free time is not directly supported as of v. 4.2.0; however, according to [this bug report](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/issues/17426), the feature is planned for eventually.

The "large-enough time signature route" is one of the two commonly prescribed ways to accomplish free time. The other is the use `Tools > Measures > Join selected measures`.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to split the sequence into smaller measures and hide time signatures and barlines for the passage, In MuseScore select the element and deselect 'visible' in the properties tab, then optionally deselect View > Show > Show Invisible. The advantage of doing this rather than putting everything into one huge measure is that the passage can be automatically broken over systems if needed. If you do this you'll need to make sure any accidentals are shown correctly.

The example can be engraved as ten 4/4 measures with hidden barlines.

Comment: "The advantage of [splitting the sequence into smaller measures with hidden time signatures] rather than putting everything into one huge measure is that the passage can be broken over systems if needed": Surely any software that supports unmeasured music also supports system breaks independently of measure boundaries, doesn't it?

Comment: @phoog This question is about MuseScore which doesn't yet offer unmeasured music. Finale now does offer unmeasured music and split measures, but even the Finale manual suggests my method as an alternative.

Comment: I see the advantage of this method, but there is also disadvantage in form of extra spacing that MuseScore (and probably Finale as well) adds to each invisible measure. But I guess one can adjust it somewhere.

Comment: @user1079505 In Finale at least it's adjustable.

Comment: @user1079505 Format > Style > Measure > set "Note to barline" and "Barline to note" to 0.